# How can I count locally by a custom condition in dataframe python3

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe called DF which contains two types of information: datetime and sentence(string).

```
0   2019-02-01  point say give choice invest motor today money...
1   2019-02-01  get inside car drive drunk excuse bad driving ...
2   2019-02-01  look car snow know buy car snow
3   2019-02-01  drive home car day terrify experience stay least
4   2019-02-01  quid way ferry nice trip enjoy land list celeb...
... ... ...
35818   2021-09-30  choice life drive type car holiday type carava...
35819   2021-09-30  scarlet carson bloody marvellous big car lover...
35820   2021-09-30  podcast adriano great episode dude weird car d...
35821   2021-09-30  scarlet carson smugly cruise traffic know driv...
35822   2021-09-30  hornet know fuel shortage brexit destroy suppl...
```

Now I generate a word list to seek whether the sentence contains these string:

```
word_list=['drive','car','buy','fuel','electric','panic','tax','second hand','petrol','auto']
```

I only need to count once if the word in word list appears in the sentence, here comes my solution

```
set_list=[]
for word in word_list:
    for sentence in DF['new_processed_text']:
        if word in sentence:
            set_list.append(sentence)
count=len(set(set_list))
```

However, this will work for the whole dataset, and I want to do the process by day.

I have no ideas about dataframe.groupby, should I need that?

Comment: Are all sentences unique? If not, should each entry add to the counter or should it only be counted once (as in your solution, because the set will remove duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [pd.DataFrame.loc method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [pd.Series.value_counts() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [pandas string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html) for your purposes:

In aggregate:

```
len(df.loc[df['new_processed_text'].str.contains('|'.join(word_list), regex=True)].index)
```

Processing per day:

```
df.loc[df['new_processed_text'].str.contains('|'.join(word_list), regex=True), 'date_column'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicates first and then use the string methods of pandas `Series` objects.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['abc def', 'def xyz ijk', 'xyz ijk', 'abc def', 'abc def', 'ijk mn', 'def xyz'])

words = ['abc', 'xyz']
s_prime = s.drop_duplicates()
contains_word = s_prime.str.contains("|".join(words))
print(contains_word.sum())
```

In your case, `s = DF['new_processed_text']` and `words = word_list`.

I forgot the per day part, which @Vladimir Vilimaitis provides in his answer with his last line.